# Starting supervisor with init fails

Tags: linux, debian, python, shell, supervisord

I installed supervisor using pip on my debian 7 installation. I then grabbed this file and moved it here: */etc/init.d/supervisord*

```
https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts/blob/master/debian-norrgard
```

Then I ran:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/supervisord
update-rc.d supervisord defaults
```

However, when I run the command supervisord the program starts fine, but when I run:

```
service supervisord start
```

I get no error or message, but supervisor doesn't actually start. How can I find out what is going on and why it isn't starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I installed supervisor using pip on my debian 7 installation.

Why would you go and do a thing like that?!? :)

There's a perfectly good supervisor package in debian's apt repo. Why not use that? That package has been well-vetted, and is configured to work seamlessly with your specific linux distro and version - none of this mucking around required.

A general rule of linuxing is this: **always** use packages from your OS's package repo, unless requirements dictate otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The apt-get Debian one is very outdated and supervisor suggests installing the up to date version so I was aprehensive about that

Comment: Have you tried it? There hasn't been a whole lot of change in supervisor, so it's likely the older version will work just fine for you.

Comment: The Debian apt-get version of supervisor is over 4 years old with quite a few changes I don't really want to use it

Comment: The debian supervisor version is 3.0 which doesn't support logging to syslog nor stop/killasgroup. I guess that is good enough reason to not use the debian package.